# Throughput or Standard Deviation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Once after execution is completed in JMeter, in the summary report, whether I need consider throughput value or standard deviation values for the result analysis purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You must consider both of the values in order to analyze the results.

**In the Summary Report:**

The **Throughput**: is the number of requests per unit of time (seconds, minutes, hours) that are sent to your server during the test.

The **throughput** is the real load processed by your server during a run but it does not tell you anything about the performance of your server during this same run. This is the reason why you need both measures in order to get a **real idea** about your server’s performance during a run. The **response time** tells you how fast your server is handling a given load.

The **Response time**: is the elapsed time from the moment when a given request is sent to the server until the moment when the last bit of information has returned to the client.

**Average**: This is the Average (Arithmetic mean μ = 1/n * Σi=1…n xi) Response time of your total samples.

**Min** and **Max** are the minimum and maximum response time.

Now, **An important** thing to understand is that the mean value can be very **misleading** as it does not show you how close (or far) your values are from the average.For this purpose, we need the **Deviation** value since the Average value can be the Same for the different response time of the samples!!

**Deviation**:  The **standard deviation (σ)** measures the mean distance of the values to their average (μ).It gives you a good idea of the **dispersion or variability** of the measures to their mean value.

The following equation show how the **standard deviation (σ)** is calculated:

**σ = 1/n * √ Σi=1…n (xi-μ)2**

For Details, see [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html)!!

So, if the **deviation** value is **low compared** to the mean value, it will indicate you that your measures are not dispersed (or mostly close to the mean value) and that the mean value is **significant**.